# PHPUnit testing failure?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

My code

```
<?php

require('PHPUnit/Autoload.php');

class MyProceduralTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testDumb()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

}
?>
```

I got the error at the time of running my phpunit test.

i got the error:

## phpunit tests

PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.

E

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 4.00Mb

There was 1 error:

1) C:\xampp\htdocs\Yuvaraj\General\PHPUnit test\tests\tests.phpt
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Invalid sections formats in test file: C:\xampp\htdocs\Yuvaraj\General\PHPUnit test\tests\tests.phpt

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Errors: 1.

Comment: You should not use outdated libraries. PHPUnit is now at version 6.5+ and your version was released over 5 years ago

Comment: Are you trying to write a phpt test? Or a PHPUnit test

Comment: Your code seems to work using PHPUnit 5.4.6. Try to update your version.